# Fullscreen for VLC media player

Tags: vlc, fullscreen

I open vlc and the mini defaulty display shows the file I've opened. When I double click on the screen to make it fullscreen - it goes into fullscreen but the actual video is dead centered and tiny. I right click and it's already in fullscreen so I'm unsure of how to make the video fit the screen.. any advice on how to about fixing this would be GREATLY appreciated. Just downloaded a cracking movie and this is a shite situation to be in.. on a Monday! 
Cheers

Comment: Try going (in your menus) to `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Video` > `Output` and select from the dropdown `X11 video output (XCB)`.  Then close down all instances of vlc and restart.

Comment: You are an absolute belter! Mate, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Go in you menus to `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Video` > `Output` and select from the drop-down `X11 video output (XCB)`.  Close down vlc and restart it.